# Find base of subspace $U=\{A\in M_3:S^{-1}AS=D\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S \in M_3(\mathbb R)$ is some invertible matrices, find a base and dimension of subspace $U$, where $U$ is set of all matrices $A\in U$ for which $S^{-1}AS$ is some diagonal matrix.

I only know one base and that is Identical matrix since $S^{-1}IS=S^{-1}S=I$ and that is diagonal matrix, is there any other base?

Comment: Am I understanding this right, that $S$ is fixed for $U$?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: According to your definition, $U$ is a singleton, it contains exactly one element, namely $SDS^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a fixed invertible matrix. The definition is
$$U = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) : S^{-1}AS \text{ is a diagonal matrix}\}$$

Let $A \in U$ such that $S^{-1}AS = D = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n)$. We have

$$A = S^{-1}DS = S^{-1}(\lambda_1E_{11} + \cdots + \lambda_n E_{nn})S = \lambda_1 S^{-1}E_{11}S + \cdots+ \lambda_n S^{-1}E_{nn}S$$

where $(E_{rs})_{ij} = \delta_{ir}\delta_{js}$. Therefore

$$U = \operatorname{span}\{S^{-1}E_{11}S, \ldots, S^{-1}E_{nn}S\}$$

Furthermore, the set $\{S^{-1}E_{11}S, \ldots, S^{-1}E_{nn}S\}$ is linearly independent as an image of a linearly independent set $\{E_{11}, \ldots, E_{nn}\}$ by the invertible linear map $X \mapsto S^{-1}XS$.

Hence $\{S^{-1}E_{11}S, \ldots, S^{-1}E_{nn}S\}$ is a basis for $U$.

Comment: lets spectrum of $A\in Mn(\mathbb R)$ is ${\lambda1,\lambda2,\cdots,\lambda_n}$ and have n element and if I have
$W=\{M\in Mn: AM=MD\}$ can you help me to find a base, I try on the same way but it is not working, i try that $A=SDS^{-1}$, but even that can not help me, do you have some idea?

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić It's not working because this is a different problem. What is $D$, a fixed diagonal matrix?

Comment: soryy i forgot to write yes it is diagonal matrix which have diagonal entries $\lambda1,\lambda 2...,\lambda n$

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2320839/144766

Comment: thank you so much